# passing query array to codeigniter view

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

iam facing problem in passing array to view.
this is my controller code..

```
function mobile_view_post($a)
    {
        log_message('debug',__FILE__.', '.__LINE__.', '.__CLASS__.'/'.__METHOD__.'/'.__FUNCTION__.'');
        $this->load->model('Mmobiles');
        data['message']=$this->Mmobiles->mobile_view_post($a);
        $this->load->view('mobile_view_post',$data);
        log_message('debug',__FILE__.', '.__LINE__.', '.__CLASS__.'/'.__METHOD__.'/'.__FUNCTION__.'');

    }
```

model code return more than 5 rows..

```
function mobile_view_post($a)
    {
        log_message('debug',__FILE__.', '.__LINE__.', '.__CLASS__.'/'.__METHOD__.'/'.__FUNCTION__.'');
        //$output=false;
        $this->db->select('c1,c2,c3,c4');
        $this->db->from('ci_posts');
        $this->db->where('mobile_number',$a);
        $q=$this->db->get();
        $this->db->last_query();
        log_message('debug','******query '.$this->db->last_query().'  ********');
        if($q->num_rows()>=1)
        {

            return $q->row_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return 'No Reports';
        }



    } // end mobile_view_post
```

but this code is not working.below line giving me error in controller

```
 data['message']=$this->Mmobiles->mobile_view_post($a);
```

view code:

```
<?php
print_r($message);
?>
```

Comment: define $data as a PHP variable. In your code it is not a variable - with no $.

Comment: thanks Aidas ..my codeigniter is not showing any error except 500 error. is there any config setting to show errors

Comment: Try this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

Comment: If above doesn't help, there may be a php error log on your server, would most likely be in the same place as your apache logs.

Comment: if you need 5 rows in array use return $q->result_array(); instead of $q->row_array() which return only a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
data['message']=$this->Mmobiles->mobile_view_post($a);
```

to

```
$data['message']=$this->Mmobiles->mobile_view_post($a);
```

And error messages are defined in index.php - make sure you are running in "development" environment to see the errors.